# Proxy http:battuta.medunes.net in angular in production

Tags: angular, api, nginx, proxy, production

I am using http://battuta.medunes.net for getting all states and cities. I had to create a proxyconfig.json file in order to be able to access this endpoint. It worked perfectly fine in my local but after I ran ng build --prod and deployed the dist folder using Nginx over AWS, I am again unable to access this API.

**proxyconfig.json**

> {
>       "/api":{
>           "target": "http://battuta.medunes.net",
>           "secure": false,
>           "changeOrigin": true
>       } }

Also tried adding below snippet as per some articles, but this too didn't work-

Could someone please suggest a solution?

**error in console in production-**

> Http failure response for
>   http://domainname.com/api/region/in/all/?key=493bd49cae3f258d1639ad3f16348bdd:
>   404 Not Found

Comment: Please don't take pictures of JSON or errors, add the actual text to your question

Comment: Hey @JamesZ , I have removed the pictures and added the actual text as suggested by you. Could you please let me know if you can help me out with this issue?